# "Error generating the Discovery document for this api" when trying to build a drive service, starting 2/14/2013

Tags: google-drive-api

I am intermittently getting this error when calling build on a drive service. I am able to reproduce this with a simple program which has the JSON credentials stored to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import sys
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import Credentials

json_creds = open('creds.txt', 'r').read()
creds = Credentials.new_from_json(json_creds)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = creds.authorize(http)

try:
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
except Exception:
    sys.exit(-1)
```

When I run this in a loop, I am seeing a rather high number of errors, this code in a loop fails 15-25% of the time for me.

```
i=0; while [ $i -lt 100 ]; do python jsoncred.py || echo FAIL ; i=$(( $i + 1 )); done | grep FAIL | wc -l
```

Now when I take this same code, and just replace 'drive' by 'oauth2', the code runs without problems

I have confirmed that the OAuth token that I am using is valid and have the correct scopes:

"expires_in": 2258,

"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",

Looking at my app logs, this seems to have started 2/14/2013 1PM PST. I did not push any new code, so I wonder if this a problem with the API. Is there a bug in the API causing this ?

Comment: Through an HTTPS proxy I observed: 1. The same exact HTTP request https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest ( including headers ) sometimes succeeds, and sometimes fails. 2. Output from the failure case is: ` { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalidConfiguration", "message": "There was an error generating the Discovery document for this api. Please try again later." } ], "code": 500, "message": "There was an error generating the Discovery document for this api. Please try again later." } } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google are seeing some reports of increased error rates for the discovery document. Please just retry on 500 error for now, and you should be successful.

One could argue that you should have retry logic for this call anyway, since it is good practice, but the current levels are too high, so, sorry about that.

*Update:* this should now be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Ali. The best workaround I have found is to save the discover result when it succeeds, and then use build_from_document() instead of build() temporarily - all my errors went away when I used that.

Also when we looked at the status of the drive API, it was still marked as healthy when the failure rate I was seeing was between 10-25%, is there something that can be done to have the API health status reflect a high rate of API failures? That would have saved us hours of debugging.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely using the correct approach. Those health statuses are automatic based on the actual global error rate, and if it was 10% it would certainly trigger. The problem here is that the discovery service is actually a different service to the Drive API.

Comment: Thanks KA. Your workaround saved us hours of debugging. Unfortunately we were also seeing a 20% failure rate. I find this reasonably disappointing, especially considering the high standard that is set by the Google Drive API.

Comment: See update above, this should now be fixed. Thanks for your time and patience :D